# Using $this -> in ob_get_contents(); returns array instead of string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using ob_get_contents(); to load a theme in which I like to use $this -> pages. If I print $this -> pages in the function it returns a propper string. But if I insert it in my theme file, it returns an emtpy array. Has somebody an idea why this happens? Here is my code:

```
public function getContentDisplay($theme_derivative, $search_key) {

  ob_start();
  include('./themes/myfolder/theme.php');
  $replace = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean(); ...


       //theme.php:
       <section class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 lucaSectionContent">
                   <%my_content_hauptbereich%>

           <?php var_dump($this -> pages); ?> //return an empty array
       </section>

//content function:

$pages = "<a href=\"?id=".$this -> main_id."&offset=".$previous_offset ."".$limit."\" ";

                           $pages .= " title=\"".$the_page_info."\" ";

                           $pages .= ">".$page_count."</a>";



                           $this -> pages = $pages;
```

Comment: Can you share code that works, and not only parts of it? What does `$this`  reference?

Comment: I found out that is has nothing to do with ob_get_contents();

Comment: Then please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `$this` can *only* be used within the scope of a method to refer to the current object. Included files inherit the local variables, but not `$this`.

If you need the object, assign it to a local variable first (eg `$object = $this`) and then use the variable.